# How to customize GCP Dataflow from PubSub to Text file on GCS

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We have a template GCP Dataflow from PubSub to Text file on GCS.

Before write to GCS, i would like to process each message from pubsub before write to GCS.

I came across this [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToText.java) on GitHub , but I am not sure where do I update the code and is there a way to print each message from PubSub ?

Comment: What language are you using to build your pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

The code from Github is a Dataflow Pipeline. You can run the pipeline as a non-template job, usually to test that the pipeline works.

If you want to run it as a template you will have to [create and stage the template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-templates)

To create the template you will have to compile it, it is recommended to use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to compile it.

```
 mvn compile exec:java \
 -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.myclass \
 -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
              --project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID \
              --stagingLocation=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/staging \
              --templateLocation=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code by applying a [DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) right after the [PubSub Read](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToText.java#L158) in that code, e.g.

```
pipeline
    .apply("Read PubSub Events", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()))
    .apply(ParDo.of([YourMessageProcessingDoFnHere]))
    .apply(
        options.getWindowDuration() + " Window",
```